# Omap3 defconfig missing

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, beagleboard, omap

I wanted to cross compile kernel for Beaglebone Omap3 but I could not find the Omap3 defconfig at arch/arm/configs.

Can anyone point me out which defconfig I need to use to get Beaglebone Omap3 kernel compile ?

Comment: The BeagleBone uses an AM335x SoC, *NOT* an OMAP3.

Comment: OP is pointing to BeagleBone which has OMAP3 , Its Beagle Bone Black which has AM335X. http://www.ti.com/devnet/docs/catalog/companyfolder.tsp?actionPerformed=companyFolder&companyId=3818